# Displaying all Django-taggit tags for each given object

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to display all the django-taggit tags related to the given object when I'm querying.

I've tried adding this function within my search_result.html template like this but no tags are being displayed:

```
{% if  page_obj.object_list %}
       <ol class="row top20">

{% for result in page_obj.object_list %}

          <div class="showcase col-sm-6 col-md-4">
           <a href="{{ result.object.get_absolute_url }}">
              <h3>{{result.object.title}}</h3>
              <img src="{{ result.object.image }}" class="img-responsive">
           </a>

<!-- I want to display them in the span below -->
      <div class="text-center">
          <span class="label label-info">{{ result.object.ptags.name }}</span>
      </div>


         </div>
{% endfor %}
      </ol>
   </div>
{% endif %}
```

My Models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255, default='')
    slug = models.SlugField(null=True, blank=True, unique=True, max_length=255, default='')
    description = models.TextField(default='')

    ptags = TaggableManager()

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def _ptags(self):
        return [t.name for t in self.ptags.all()]

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product',
                       kwargs={'slug': self.slug})


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

My custom forms.py function:

```
from haystack.forms import FacetedSearchForm


class FacetedProductSearchForm(FacetedSearchForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data = dict(kwargs.get("data", []))
        self.ptag = data.get('ptags', [])
        super(FacetedProductSearchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def search(self):
        sqs = super(FacetedProductSearchForm, self).search()

        if self.ptag:
            query = None
            for ptags in self.ptag:
                if query:
                    query += u' OR '
                else:
                    query = u''
                query += u'"%s"' % sqs.query.clean(ptags)
            sqs = sqs.narrow(u'ptags_exact:%s' % query)

        return sqs
```

And I'm passing the forms into the views like this:

```
class FacetedSearchView(BaseFacetedSearchView):

    form_class = FacetedProductSearchForm
    facet_fields = ['ptags']
    template_name = 'search_result.html'
    paginate_by = 6
    context_object_name = 'object_list'
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this instead

```
<span class="label label-info">{{ result.object.ptags.names }}</span>
```

---

You can loop over the `ptags.names` queryset to display individual tags, like this:

```
{% for tag in result.object.ptags.names %}
    {{ tag }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Awesome, I'm getting this output: `<QuerySet ['Family', 'Group', 'Solo']>`, how can I get each value in an individual format like this: `Family`  `Group`  `Solo`  ?

Comment: Thanks so much, I've added the loop like this: `<span class="label label-info">{% for tag in result.object.ptags.names %}{{ tag }}{% endfor %}</span>`. It's been displayed correctly for the individual tags but if I have more than one tag for a given object, I get this output: `FamilyGroupSolo`, all stuck together.

Comment: Try adding a space around `{{tag}}`, so like this: `{% for tag in result.object.ptags.names %} {{ tag }} {% endfor %}`

Comment: Made it work! Instead of looping directly inside of the span I did this: `{% for tag in result.object.ptags.names %}
    <div class="text-center">
          <span class="label label-info">{{ tag }}</span>
      </div>
{% endfor %}`

Comment: I really appreciate your help, thank you so much! Have a good day :)